# Element wise comparison within same np array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison, element

I am trying to compare values within a np array, sequentially appending them and creating a vector that has the smallest values of the np array in it (the vector should have the length N*2 - 1, if the matrix dimensions are NxN). I have attached an image to illustrate the problem better. Basically, I want to start at position [0,0] and then sequentially compare the values in [0,1] and [1,0], etc. When a nan is compared with a number, it automatically selects the number. For the comparison of two numbers, i.e. values in [0,2] and [1,1], it should select the smaller one.

[image: 5x5nparray]

The reason the matrix is an upper triangular matrix with nan values listed instead of 0's, is that the matrix is symmetric and I thought that would make the computation of the vector with the smallest values in it easier.

Below, is some code I wrote, in an attempt to solve the problem. I realize that the indexes i and j are moving incorrectly through the matrix, however, I am totally lost on how to do it correctly.

NOTE: I didn't include the code that generates the matrix, simply because it is part of a larger script and I wanted to avoid confusion. I denoted dim = 5 for the matrix (mat) of size 5x5 in this example. Furthermore, this is only an example where the minimal values happen to be [mat[0,0],mat[0,1],mat[1,1],mat[1,2]...].

```
x=[]
dim = 5
for i in range(dim-1):
    for j in range(dim-1):

    if mat[i,j+1] > mat[i+1,j]:
        x.append(mat[i+1,j])

    elif mat[i,j+1] < mat[i+1,j]:
        x.append(mat[i,j+1])

    elif m.isnan(mat[i,j+1]):
        x.append(mat[i+1,j])

    elif m.isnan(mat[i+1,j]):
        x.append(mat[i,j+1])
```

I'd appreciate any help/tips with this.

EDIT:

Thanks for all of your input. I think I figured out how to do it. I think that there is probably a more pythonic way of doing this, however, I am lacking the skills as of now. The code blow should be able to walk through an upper triangular matrix picking the smallest values and appending them to a vector. In the case of this example I mean vector = [2.8, 4.7, 7.6, 5.5, 5.3, 0.18, -3.9, -11.1, -20.1].

```
import numpy as np


dim = 5
mat = np.array([[2.802, 4.713, 9.581, 15.339, 22.273],
     [np.nan, 7.647, 5.559, 7.317, 10.250],
     [np.nan, np.nan, 5.383, 0.184, -0.882],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -3.992, -11.124],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -20.192]])
mat_to_vect =  np.reshape(mat, (dim**2))
min_vect = [mat_to_vect[0]]

i = 1
j = dim

while i and j < dim**2-1:

    if mat_to_vect[i] > mat_to_vect[j]:
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[j])
        j += dim
        i += dim

    elif mat_to_vect[i] < mat_to_vect[j]:
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[i])
        j += 1
        i += 1

    elif m.isnan(mat_to_vect[i]):
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[j])
        j += dim
        i += dim

    elif m.isnan(mat_to_vect[j]):
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[i])
        j += 1
        i += 1

min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[dim**2-1])
```

Comment: Is what you are trying to do, append the smallest number from each column to a _vector_ ? Could you please explain as to what the "smallest values" refers to?

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. If I start at mat[0,0] then I would like to compare values mat[0,1] and mat[1,0]. In this case, mat[1,0] = nan, so mat[0,1] should be appended to x. The next step is comparing mat[0,2] and mat[1,1], here mat[1,1] < mat[0,2], so mat[1,1] is appended to x. This should repeat until the position mat[4,4] is reached and len(x) = 9. In my thinking, the vector x should now include the lowest values from mat, with a length of 9.

Comment: You should consider the option of using a built-in method like the numpy.matrix.min() see the numpy documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.min.html. Similar solution but possibly better for your case has been provided by @NaN.

Comment: Do you really want to "greedily" pick the smaller branch at each step or is what you ultimately want the path from top left to bottom right with the smallest sum? The two are not necessarily the same. Or do you want something still different?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, everyone. I spent some time thinking about the problem and I am not sure if I can solve it by using nan functions for the minimum. In the case of the matrix posted above (which I should have added in my initial question) the desired end result is x = [2.8, 4.7, 7.6, 5.5, 5.3, 0.18, -3.9, -11.1, -20.1], I am then using x to plot these values. The values represent a 'minimum' case for a chemical reaction. The matrix generates all 'reaction paths'. I am trying to walk through it and pick the smaller value at each step.

Comment: If I use the nan functions for the minimum values, per row and column, I can get array([  2.802,   4.713,   5.383,  -3.992, -20.192]), as @NaN posted. However, the values 7.6, 5.5, 0.18, and -11.12 are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


dim = 5
mat = np.array([[2.802, 4.713, 9.581, 15.339, 22.273],
     [np.nan, 7.647, 5.559, 7.317, 10.250],
     [np.nan, np.nan, 5.383, 0.184, -0.882],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -3.992, -11.124],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -20.192]])
mat_to_vect =  np.reshape(mat, (dim**2))
min_vect = [mat_to_vect[0]]

i = 1
j = dim

while i and j < dim**2-1:

    if mat_to_vect[i] > mat_to_vect[j]:
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[j])
        j += dim
        i += dim

    elif mat_to_vect[i] < mat_to_vect[j]:
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[i])
        j += 1
        i += 1

    elif m.isnan(mat_to_vect[i]):
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[j])
        j += dim
        i += dim

    elif m.isnan(mat_to_vect[j]):
        min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[i])
        j += 1
        i += 1

min_vect.append(mat_to_vect[dim**2-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

this is too big for a comment, but may serve to provide some options to your final solution.

```
a = [[2.802, 4.713, 9.581, 15.339, 22.273],
     [np.nan, 7.647, 5.559, 7.317, 10.250],
     [np.nan, np.nan, 5.383, 0.184, -0.882],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -3.992, -11.124],
     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -20.192]]
b = np.nanmin(a, axis=0)
b
array([  2.802,   4.713,   5.383,  -3.992, -20.192])
```

Now if -20.192 the desired result, then the final solution is simple.
Effectively, this setup of using an np.triu with the lower portion set to np.nan allows one to use nan functions to get the minimums.  In your case, get the minimum by column, then finally by row, if -20.192 would be the desired result.
If that is not the final case, the steps of proceeding from cell (0,0) sequentially through the array need to be further defined. In short, np.nanmin seems to be what you are after.

ADDENDUM
Or you can do it sequentially, which I think your additions in the comments are referring to

```
a
array([[  2.802,   4.713,   9.581,  15.339,  22.273],
       [    nan,   7.647,   5.559,   7.317,  10.25 ],
       [    nan,     nan,   5.383,   0.184,  -0.882],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,  -3.992, -11.124],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan, -20.192]])

b = [np.nanmin(a[:i], axis=0) for i in range(1, a.shape[0]+1)]
b
[array([  2.802,   4.713,   9.581,  15.339,  22.273]),
 array([  2.802,   4.713,   5.559,   7.317,  10.25 ]),
 array([ 2.802,  4.713,  5.383,  0.184, -0.882]),
 array([  2.802,   4.713,   5.383,  -3.992, -11.124])
 array([  2.802,   4.713,   5.383,  -3.992, -20.192])]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I replied above in the comments section.

Comment: @Jond Is the addition above what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am not sure how the code above will get x = [2.8, 4.7, 7.6, 5.5, 5.3, 0.18, -3.9, -11.1, -20.1]. I edited my original post, which gives me the desired result. The while loop basically checks at each point which values is smaller and then appends it. If it is comparing between a nan and a number it chooses the number.